# jQuery and Bootstrap: Warning on console - Failed resource

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Some time ago I updated my jQuery and since then my project has stopped executing Javascript all over.

This is the script in the Index page I use to test the use of JS:

```
@section scripts{
 <script src="~/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script>
     console.log("hi");
 </script>
```

}

This is the result in the console:

[image]

What catches my eye is:

**Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery. jQuery must be included before Bootstrap's JavaScript.**

Going in detail on that alert I see:

```
if (typeof jQuery === 'undefined') {
  throw new Error('Bootstrap\'s JavaScript requires jQuery. 
jQuery must be included before Bootstrap\'s JavaScript.')}
```

Checking jQuery now:

[image]

It has a tag saying its extrange (extraño in spanish)

**UPDATE**

I decided to uninstall jQuery and bootstrap and reinstall them: First jQuery and then Bootstrap.

After that, Bower looks like this.

[image]

Still not working tho

Checking the Network console (as required by user) I got this:

[image]

There is a bunch of kendo ui not loading

**Note:** I installed kendo ui back in the day because I needed a editable grid, but since it sucked, I made my own and discarded kendo ui.

**UPDATE x2**

**Note: I'm working on ASP.NET Core**

It seems that the answer might be that jQuery must load before Bootstrap.

To check this I'm going thru diferent files (bower.json, _Layout.cshtml) since I don't usually reference the scripts in each file. My project usually has a reference in the background that load these scripts into each view automaticaly I believe.

For example, I never reference the kendo ui on the Index page, but in the Console I see that it is failing to load (because it is uninstalled) but is been called.

For this I checked the _Layout.cshtml

[image]

Here I can see my references that work for the whole project I believe and it seems the order is correct.

Hope this help to any reply! Thanks

Comment: Can you check the browser network panel, whether jQuery (jquery-3.2.1.min.js) is loading or not??? I guess jQuery library file is not loading to the browser.

Comment: @Shiladitya updated! thanks for your reply! Looks like it is being loaded, although the console still shows the message "Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery. jQuery must be included before Bootstrap's JavaScript." and all the kendo messages

Comment: In your situation, **jQuery** is loading but **after bootstrap.js**, thats why you are getting an error. One more thing, why two versions of jQuery you are loading one is **jquery.js** another is **jquery-3.2.1-min.js** ????

Comment: I'm loading two jquerys because I was including the **jquery-3.2.1-min.js** in the src of the console.log message I included to test my JS, but I deleted that already. It was not on purpose, it was just for a test. Could you please tell me how to make the jQuery load before bootstrap?

Answer (score 2):

Here you go with two jsfiddle example.

`https://jsfiddle.net/r9tnow7L/`

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

In the above fiddle, **bootstrap** is loading before **jQuery** as I specified an order in the **external resources**.

`https://jsfiddle.net/r9tnow7L/1/`

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

In this fiddle, **jQuery** is loading before **bootstrap**, check the **ordering** in **external resources**.

Please check the browser network panel.
This might help you to understand the order of the library file.

Comment: I'm tempted to edit the bower.json file. In this file, on the dependencies and resolutions sections, bootstrap appears first. I understand your answer but I'm not sure in which part should I edit the application in order to alter the execution. bower.json would be correct?

Comment: Not necessarily. Most of the time I don't tag my scripts on the views/html but my JS was still working on all the project. As a proof of that, I added a src of **jquery-3.2.1-min.js** to  my view and you saw that jquery was duplicated, although I only added one, another was is running in the background for all the project I believe

Comment: I added an update on the question. I'm working on asp.net core and we have a file: _layout.cshtml that contains the references to the scripts used in the project. Sorry for no adding this info before